# Slack App (bot) send private messages to multiple users

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack, slack-api

i'm trying to create a chess bot to play with other users on the workspace. I can't figure out how to create a private conversation including 2 users (the 2 players) and the bot user. To play in private.

I tried to use the slack api but it does not work.

Comment: https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.create and https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.invite may help

Comment: I saw this doc. But i can't invite my bot.

Comment: That is a different issue, please clarify your question. To my understand you're asking for help "to create a private conversation including 2 users"

Comment: it's clearly asked "2 users and the bot user".

Comment: Then I am not clear on your issue. What is the problem that you are having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using a "multi-person direct message" (MPIM). It allows you to create a new / or join an existing direct message channel with multiple users, e.g. 2 players and your bot user.

A MPIM is different from a private channel as it does not require a dedicated name and you can create multiple in the same workspace as long as it contains a different set of users.

To open a MPIM call the API method [`conversations.open`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.open) with your bot user token and provide the user IDs of the two users in the `users` parameter. You will get a channel ID in return, which you can use later to resume the conversation. Alternatively you can just open it again with the same list of users.